# How do I express this constraint with JPA?

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public enum Scope {
  A, B, C...
}

@Entity
public class User {

    ...

    Scope scope; // enum, see above

    @ElementCollecton
    List<Long> numbers;

    ...
}
```

My problem is that I don't know how to express the following constraint with either JPA or directly in my Postgres database:
**There can only be one User with a scope x who has a number y.**

In order to clarify what I mean, some pseudocode:

This is valid (Bobs 3 does not colide with Toms 3 since Bob has a different scope):
Tom(scope=A,numbers=[1,2,3,4]), Carl(scope=A,number=[5,6,7]), Bob(scope=B,numbers=[3, 42, 100])

But this is invalid (Carls 4 violates the constraint since Tom has the same scope and also a 4 in his list):
Tom(scope=A,numbers=[1,2,3,4]), Carl(scope=A,number=[4,5,6,7]), Bob(scope=B,numbers=[3, 42, 100])

Comment: Thanks to the bean validation introduced with JEE6, You can build a custom validator with whatever validating logic you want. A simple example can be found here (just a quick pick from google results): http://silentwalker.wordpress.com/2009/04/07/custom-validation-in-hibernate/

Comment: this looks like an answer @ifischer..

Comment: The custom validator will enforce the constraint at the java level, but it looks like popopaule is looking for a constraint at the database level.

Comment: custom validator would also have to be executing queries in order to validate, which is usually undesirable

Comment: thanks for your input, but Affe is correct. I need a constraint at database level.

Comment: Ok. Then I guess you need to write a Postgres Trigger http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/triggers.html

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is lie to JPA about the foreign key to the element collection and then put an ordinary unique constraint on the combination of scope + number in the collection table.

```
@Column(name="SCOPE")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)//or whatever
private Scope scope;

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name= "NUMBERS" ,
    joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"),
                  @JoinColumn(name = "USER_SCOPE", referencedColumnName = "SCOPE") }),
@Column(name="NUMBER")
private List<Long> numbers;
```

Obviously USER_SCOPE is totally unnecessary in the normalized model, but by telling JPA it's part of the key you can trick the provider into maintaining the column for you.